# How to check if USB WiFi-Adapter is not working or router is out of range?

Tags: fedora, wifi, usb

I'm trying to use the TL-WN725N as an USB WiFi-Adapter with Fedora 20.
As it is Version 2, it does not work out of the box.

- I installed the driver (first time I compiled myself, second time I used a package from a third party repo)
- now, the network is recognized but I cannot connect
- the connectivity sign shows zero bars

Usually I would assume that the stick's range is too small, but other people using it, reported that the range is quite good. Considering that my Computer is only 5-7m and a wall away from the router, I'm tempted to say, something else is not working correctly.

Does anyone have an idea on how to check if the problem is caused by the driver or simply by the adapter's range being too small?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would confirm the steps that you used to compile the driver yourself. This driver is known not to work out of the box, and so compiling it from source appears to be your only option. This guide shows the steps, for Ubuntu, titled:[Ubuntu Linux TL-WN725N TP-Link version 2 WiFi driver install](http://brilliantlyeasy.com/ubuntu-linux-tl-wn725n-tp-link-version-2-wifi-driver-install/).

You can modify these steps as follows for Fedora.

```
$ sudo yum install kernel-headers
$ sudo yum install kernel-devel
$ sudo yum groupinstall "Development Tools"
$ sudo yum install git
$ git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8188eu
$ cd rtl8188eu
$ make all
$ make install
$ insmod 8188eu.ko
```

Now check to see if the WLAN NIC is detected.

```
$ ifconfig
```

Comment: `make all` gave me the following error Output `rtl8188eu]# make all
make ARCH=x86_64 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/3.16.2-200.fc20.x86_64/build M=/home/GlaDOS/rtl8188eu  modules
make: *** /lib/modules/3.16.2-200.fc20.x86_64/build: No such file or directory.  Stop.
make: *** [modules] Error 2`

Comment: @Merlin - are you 32-bit or 64-bit Fedora 20? `uname -r`.

Comment: 64-bit `3.16.2-200.fc20.x86_64`

Comment: @Merlin - forgot a package, see updates. Need `kernel-devel`.

Comment: `make all` and `make install` worked out now, but I get `insmod: ERROR: could not insert module 8188eu.ko: Device or resource busy`

Comment: @sim I know I am not supposed to do this, but THANK YOU! I was literally jumping up and down in my room screaming "IT WORKED!".

Comment: About `insmod: ERROR: could not insert module 8188eu.ko: Device or resource busy`:

After I restarted the computer, I got `insmod: ERROR: could not load module 8188eu.ko: No such file or director` , but the adapter worked, so I suppose a restart solves the error.

Comment: @Merlin - yeah!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. I have been searching for this and got the solution here.
Just one point to add, before doing a make all, do a reboot of the machine. Otherwise the make all shows error.

```
$ sudo yum install kernel-headers
$ sudo yum install kernel-devel
$ sudo yum groupinstall "Development Tools"
$ sudo yum install git
$ git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8188eu
```

REBOOT THE DEVICE

```
$ cd rtl8188eu
$ make all
$ make install
$ insmod 8188eu.ko
```