# yum install kernel-devel: "Nothing to do"

Tags: kernel, compiling, yum

I need the `kernel-devel` package to compile a program([How to check if USB WiFi-Adapter is not working or router is out of range?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/155940/how-to-check-if-usb-wifi-adapter-is-not-working-or-router-is-out-of-range)), but when I try to install it via yum, this is the only output:

```
yum install kernel-devel
Loaded plugins: langpacks, refresh-packagekit
Nothing to do
```

If the package was already installed, it would say so.

Anyone got an idea about what is going on there?

Enabled repos:

```
yum repolist enabled
Loaded plugins: langpacks, refresh-packagekit
repo id                             repo name                             status
atlassian-hipchat                   Atlassian Hipchat                          2
fedora/20/x86_64                    Fedora 20 - x86_64                    38,597
rpmfusion-free/20/x86_64            RPM Fusion for Fedora 20 - Free          468
rpmfusion-free-updates/20/x86_64    RPM Fusion for Fedora 20 - Free - Upd    431
rpmfusion-nonfree/20/x86_64         RPM Fusion for Fedora 20 - Nonfree       203
rpmfusion-nonfree-updates/20/x86_64 RPM Fusion for Fedora 20 - Nonfree -     301
sagitter-Icecat/20/x86_64           Copr repo for Icecat owned by sagitte      2
updates/20/x86_64
```

Output of yum list `kernel-devel`:

```
yum list kernel-devel
Loaded plugins: langpacks, refresh-packagekit
Installed Packages
kernel-devel.x86_64                  3.15.10-201.fc20                   @updates
kernel-devel.x86_64                  3.16.2-200.fc20                    @updates
```

Comment: What repositories do you have active/enabled?

Comment: @EtanReisner See edit.

Comment: What is the output of `yum list kernel-devel`?

Comment: @TimothyMartin See edit.

Comment: Says they are already installed.

Comment: @EtanReisner Well, this probably means something else goes wrong during compiling.

Comment: If compilation is failing it certainly seems to suggest some other problem. Yes.

Comment: @EtanReisner Magically, it seems like it worked now, even though I changed nothing(well, I restarted, maybe that's why). Thanks though.