# How do you modprobe a program?

Tags: kernel, raspberry-pi, modprobe

I've been trying to get [this program](https://github.com/groupgets/LeptonModule/tree/master/software/v4l2lepton) to work on my Raspberry Pi for the past two days and I've gotten to step 6 which says, "At this point, you should be able to modprobe v4l2loopback".

When I ran the command at the bottom of the Github page, nothing happened. I've never worked in a Linux environment before and don't even know what modprobe means. Can a guru take a look at the link and tell me if there is more to modprobing than just running the command `./v4l2lepton /dev/videoX`?

Answer (score 3):

You're missing a link to the page in question, but even without that link I can tell you that the page is simply telling you to run `modprobe v4l2loopback`. The `modprobe` command is a way of inserting a new kernel module into the running kernel without having to rebuild the entire kernel and/or reboot the machine. Chances are you won't be able to successfully run `./v4l2lepton /dev/videoX` until after you've run `modprobe v4l2loopback` and posibly another command to insert the module and create the video device entry in `/dev`.

Comment: I've added the link, thanks for letting me know. Also, when I run `modprobe v4l2loopback` I just get an error that says `FATAL: Module v4l2loopback not found.` and I'm not sure why this is happening because I have already copied the .ko file into `/lib/modules` like the repo said to do.

Comment: Can you try "insmod /path/to/module.ko"? insmod is more limited in what it can achieve, compared to modprobe, but it allows loading modules by their filename to test in this situation.

Comment: Generally, a modprobe failure like that means you're getting the module name wrong (4-ell-2 versus 4-one-2, possibly) or that it's not readable (file permissions).

Comment: @JakGibb I ran the command `insmode /lib/modules/v4l2loopback` and it told me that the command was not found. Is there a `apt-get` for it?

Comment: Did you run insmod or insmode? insmod is the lower level program called by modprobe so it will be there.

Comment: @John since I copied the .ko file I'm sure that the name is correct and since I'm using `sudo` before my command would file permissions be a problem?

Comment: @JakGibb That was my mistake. It's strange though, when I run the command `sudo insmode /lib/modules/v4l2lepton` I get an error message that says `Error: could not insert module /lib/modules/v4l2lepton: Invalid module format`. Do you have any idea what that means?

Comment: See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/170503/insmod-error-could-not-insert-module-8188eu-ko-invalid-module-format for my best guess at the "Invalid module format" error.

Comment: You need to provide the full path to the `.ko` file, not the directory it is in.

Comment: @John I don't think that will help me because I just compiled the .ko file so I don't think it would have a different header then the kernal.

Comment: @StephenHarris That was a the full directory. v4l2lepton is not a directory it's the .ko file.

Comment: @crystal-pritzker see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I've justed tested this on a Raspberry Pi I had lying around, and it worked perfectly.
Perhaps you missed a step with the instructions, or were using an older kernel version to begin with.

Here are the steps I took which worked.
You didn't mention which OS you were running on the Pi, but I'm using a fresh install of the latest version of [raspbian](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/) (2016-05-27 with kernel 4.4).

**[root]#:** apt-get install bc libncurses5-dev

**[root]#:** wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/notro/rpi-source/master  /rpi-source -O /usr/bin/rpi-source && sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/rpi-source && /usr/bin/rpi-source -q --tag-update

**[root]#:** rpi-source

**[root]#:** git clone https://github.com/umlaeute/v4l2loopback.git

**[root]#:** cd v4l2loopback/

**[root]#:** make

**[root]#:** cp v4l2loopback.ko /lib/modules/4.4.11+/

**[root]#:** modprobe v4l2loopback

Now to confirm the module is actually loaded:

**[root]#:** lsmod |grep v4l2loopback
v4l2loopback           27026  0
videodev              172779  1 v4l2loopback

Comment: I did all that and even got the same confirmation that you did. But when I run the command `./vl2loopback /dev/videoX` I just get this error message: `Failed to open v4l2sing device. (No such file or directory)`.

I should point out that I copied the file into `/lib/modules/` and didn't add the 4.4.11+ at the end because when I tried to do that it gave me an error.

Comment: Well that's good, it means the original issue of the module not being able to be loaded is now resolved. As for the new issue, I'd assume that where the instructions state /dev/videoX they are expecting you to replace the 'X' with a number that relates to your video device. Try running: ls /dev/vid* to list the devices detected, and then run your command again with that device. e.g.: ./v4l2sing /dev/video0

Comment: Crystal, in your comment above you wrote: "./vl2loopback /dev/videoX" instead of "./vl2lepton /dev/videoX" (note also that "X" needs to be a number for the device, 0,1,2,3 etc.)