# No internet connection after uninstalling gnome [Fedora + Openbox]

Tags: fedora, gnome, openbox, wlan, lan

I removed gnome(running bare openbox)and now lan and wlan both do not work anymore.

I used this to set up my wifi before, but now it does not work anymore and insmod tells that the file already exists, even though I did not insert the module yet:
[How to check if USB WiFi-Adapter is not working or router is out of range?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/155940/how-to-check-if-usb-wifi-adapter-is-not-working-or-router-is-out-of-range-solv)

For lan, could be caused by a cable defect, but that is pretty unlikly. Unfortunetely, I cannot test that right now.

Anyone has any idea on how to fix this?

(Sorry for the bad writing, forced to type on a tablet right now which is a pain in the neck.)

Comment: May be Gnome took `networkmanager` with itself? Try to install it.

Comment: @kirill-a Any idea on how to that without an internet connection?

Comment: You can download it from [link](http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/n/network-manager-applet/network-manager-gnome_0.8-0ubuntu3.1_i386.deb) and connect your tablet to pc and install it by running `dpkg -i network*.deb` from folder containing it.

Comment: @kirill-a I got access to a computer, downloaded the rpm package(your link gives me .deb, not useful for Fedora), but when I try to install the package I get loads of depency errors. I will try to find a package with all the dependencies included.

Comment: Can you run `ifconfig` and add output to your answer?

Comment: @kirill-a I cannot post it here, but I only get the lo: output, no wlan or eth .

Comment: Try doing `ifconfig -a` and then run ifup command on disabled interfaces, e.g. `ifup eth0`

Comment: @kirill-a Did that for enp2s0f0 . It said that determining ip information is done. Seems like my connection is working now, yum is updating. Thank you very, very much!

Comment: Okay, I'll post this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check all interfaces by running `ifconfig -a` and then run ifup command on disabled interfaces, e.g. `ifup eth0`